# efficient method to finding the first observation where all players have had a turn in R

Tags: r, loops, match

If we have players A,B,C,D,E,F and the dataframe D has entries where each row has an entry equal to the player label and there are multiple rows.

I want to find the index at which the unique number of teams in D, which is obviously given by: `length(unique(D$names))`, is achived.

For example, we might have that the first 6 rows have names: A,B,C,D,E,F in which case the index = 6. But we might have another case where A,B,C,D,A,E,F, in which case the index =7. I've done the follwong *clunky* code:

```
   for(i in 6:60){

  if (length(unique(D$Team[1:i]))==length(unique(D$Team)))
  {
    print(i)
    break
  }
}
```

* I start at 6 since this is the minimum number of rows required

I think there is a better solution using the match function in R. something like"

```
match(length(unique(D$Team)[i]),length(unique(D$Team)))
```

Comment: Try `max(match(unique(D$Team),D$Team))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `match` gives the first occurrence of an element in a vector, you can find the positions of the first match of every unique element and then take the maximum:

```
max(match(unique(D$Team),D$Team))
```

As an example:

```
set.seed(1)
D<-data.frame(Team=sample(LETTERS[1:6],100,TRUE),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
max(match(unique(D$Team),D$Team))
#[1] 13
D$Team[1:13]
#[1] "B" "C" "D" "F" "B" "F" "F" "D" "D" "A" "B" "B" "E"
```

Comment: Thanks, as a small aside, it isn't possible to use this approach to find the number of occurences required for each team to play two times instead of just one time, is it?

Answer (score 2):

We could use `seq_along()` to get the indices of the non-duplicate elements of your vector, and attain the index of the last element by wrapping the whole thing inside `max()`.

```
# Example vector based on your question
vec <- c("A","B","C","D","A","E","F")

# Get index of last non-duplicate element
max(seq_along(vec)[!duplicated(vec)])
#[1] 7
```